# SQL Server full text search index usage

Tags: sql-server, indexing, full-text-search

I have created a full text search catalog with some indices on a table within this catalog. How can I get information about the usage of a created full text search index?

Comment: Are these usefull ?https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms174971.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving user *scans* for [full text search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) indices with [sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188755.aspx) so far:

```
SELECT FTSC.name AS CatalogName, 
       T.name AS TableName, 
       C.name AS ColumnName, 
       FTSIU.user_scans, 
       FTSIU.last_user_scan
FROM sys.fulltext_catalogs AS FTSC 
JOIN sys.fulltext_indexes AS FTSI ON FTSC.fulltext_catalog_id = FTSI.fulltext_catalog_id
JOIN sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats AS FTSIU ON FTSI.object_id = FTSIU.object_id AND FTSI.unique_index_id = FTSIU.index_id
JOIN sys.tables AS T ON FTSI.object_id = T.object_id
JOIN sys.columns AS C ON FTSI.object_id = C.object_id 
    AND FTSI.unique_index_id = C.column_id
WHERE FTSIU.database_id = DB_ID()
```

Comment: Apologies for commenting on an old post, but I don't think this works as-is (it does of course show index usage, but not exclusively the Full-Text searches necessarily). Any hits on these (not Full-Text searches) can result in the user_scans increasing. I came across this when looking at a current dba.stackexchange question, my answer contains the proof of my testing. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/334802/how-can-i-tell-if-a-full-text-index-is-being-used/334887#334887